# how do i get the service response data into the md dialog angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, angularjs-material

i have created the custom service like this

```
  app.service('userService', function($http,UrlService) {
    return {
        init: function(callback) {
            $http.get(UrlService.baseUrl +'/api/users/list').then(function(user_response) {
                callback(user_response);

            });
        }
    }
})
```

Inside of my project main controller i have used like this to get the angular material design modal.

```
  $scope.replyComplaint = function(user,complaint_id) {

        complaint_id=user._id;
        console.log(complaint_id)
        $mdDialog.show({
                controller: DialogCtrl,
                templateUrl: 'submodules/user_management/replydialog.html',
                resolve: { complaint_id : function() {return complaint_id;} },
                 locals: {
                   users: $scope.users
                 },
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                clickOutsideToClose: true,
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                $scope.response = response;
                console.log(response);
            }, function() {
                //fail
            });
    };
```

created another controller for dialog as in the angular material docs as follows

```
function DialogCtrl($scope, $rootScope, $mdDialog, users,complaintService, UrlService, $http) {
    complaintService.init(function(complaint_response) {
           $scope.complaints = complaint_response.data;
           $scope.getUsers();
        });

$scope.getUsers = function(complaint_id) {
     console.log(complaint_id);
    $scope.hide = function() {
        $mdDialog.hide();
    };
    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $mdDialog.cancel();
    };
    $scope.replyMail = function(complaint_id) {
             console.log(complaint_id);
        $http.post(UrlService.baseUrl + '/api/complaints/complaint/'+complaint_id , {
                complaint: "replyText"
            }, $scope)
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log(name);
                $state.reload();
            }, function(response) {
                console.log(name);
            });
    }
}
}
```

Now, i need to get the `user_response` data in `DialogController`. if i put `console.log('$scope.users')` inside of this `userservice.init` function, i can get the data. but not outside of it. how to get the response data outside of the userService.init function

```
 userService.init(function(user_response) {
        $scope.users = user_response.data; 
    });        //this is added in DialogController
```

Main intension is to get the `user.comlaint_id` in the post request of reply mail function . that user.complaint_id is a part of the user_response
Anyone please help me. Thanks

Comment: angular is async you can't access directly outside. You need to create a function and use inside that.

Comment: thanks for your response. I have created init function right, inside only  i am trying to access that. can you show me one example how to access that. by using rootscope.broadcast or through services itself

Comment: don't call service in init method. call service outside method and call init method in that service after $scope.users and user $scope.users in init method

Comment: Could you please show me the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
userService.init(function(user_response) {
    $scope.users = user_response.data;
    $scope.init();
});

$scope.init = function() {
You can access $scope.users here
}
```

Call any method instead of init() in which you require $scope.users

Comment: Thanks for your help. it worked. one more doubt--> i have a list of items which is showing in table and generated using ng-repeat for $scope.users. also i have a button to reply in the table for the items. if it is a same controller, i could have get the particular user id to reply. but in angular-material we are using separate controller. how to get the id of the user where clicked the reply button. can you please help me on this. thanks

Comment: tell me more about your table.. is it in dialog ?

Comment: table is not in dialog.i have a table of items generated with ng-repeat. for every item there is one button called reply button. if i click reply dialog will open with text box to enter the reply message and send button is in the dialog only. after clicking send, i have  to send the post request

Comment: You can take id with $mdDialog code. Like with controller and templates pass a dynamic id variable and get it by passing it as dependency in dialog controller. I haven't used it in angular material yet but I have used it in core angular.

Comment: `resolve: {
       comlaint_id : function() {return comlaint_id;}
      }`
Pass comlaint_id in replyComplaint method

Answer (score 2):

The `$http.get` call returns a promise, you can just use that.

```
app.service('userService', function($http,UrlService) {
  return {
    init: function(callback) {
        return $http.get(UrlService.baseUrl +'/api/users/list');
    }
  }
});
```

Controller:

```
function Dialog($scope,$rootScope, $mdDialog,userService,UrlService,$http) {
  // console.log(userService.init());

  init();

  function init() {
    userService.init().then(function(response) {
      $scope.users = response.data; 
    });
  }
}
```

This also has the advantage of easier error handling:

```
function Dialog($scope,$rootScope, $mdDialog,userService,UrlService,$http) {
  // console.log(userService.init());

  init();

  function init() {
    userService.init().then(function(response) {
      $scope.users = response.data; 
    }, function(error) {
      // handle error
    });
  }
}
```

You should read up on angular/javascript promises and their chaining mechanism: [angular promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)